# Docker and Cloudera Quick start: How to run own jar-file?

Tags: java, hadoop, docker, cloudera, bigdata

I installed Docker container and made next steps:

```
docker pull cloudera/quickstart:latest
docker images # note the hash of the image and substitute it below
docker run --privileged=true \
--hostname=quickstart.cloudera \
-t -i ${HASH} \
/usr/bin/docker-quickstart
```

So, now I have: Cloudera is running. But I cant see any local files, so how to load my own files, especially jar-file to run it with Hadoop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may mount local folder into docker container as it described in [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)

docker run -i -t -v /path/to/my/data:/opt/data image

Comment: could you specify please your command. I got in log :"docker: Error response from daemon: No command specified." I used "docker run -i -t -v /home/myfolder:/opt/data cloudera/quickstart" command

Comment: You need to add your command into that call. Command to run your jar I think.